# Name desktop workspaces (in Xubuntu)?

Tags: xubuntu, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Is it possible to name desktop workspaces?
A name would allow me to remember the type of windows I have in that workspace.

Is there a way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the application called `workspaces` either from the menu button or typing `Alt+F3` and typing `workspaces`. Then you'll find the name of the workspaces you have, you can also add and remove the workspaces. If for some reason you want to access it via the command line, you can also do it by typing `xfwm4-workspace-settings`.

I particularly don't name the workspaces, but I create a grid in which I navigate.